# How do I solve each compiling error in this program code(java)?

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve this, and I am not very fluent in java's module and call ref. Can someone help me make this program work? It's very confusing. It has a lot of problems with the pass by reference in java, along with any extra errors that I have in there. I keep getting errors like incompatible types and cannot find symbols.

```
    //This program is designed to have the user enter 10 golf scores, then display them in        ascending order.

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SortedGolfScoresMT
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    //Declares the size for the variable, which is 10
    int SIZE = 10;

    //Declares the array and utilize it with SIZE variable
    int[] scores = new int[SIZE];

    getScores(scores, SIZE);

    insertionSort(scores, SIZE);

    displayScores(scores, SIZE);
   }

public static int[] getScores(int scores[], int SIZE)
{
    // Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declares the index as a counter
    int index;

    //Get the scores for each golf player
    for ( index = 0; index <= SIZE - 1; index++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the golf scores for player " + (index + 1)   + ": ");
        scores[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    return scores[index];
}


public static int[] insertionSort(int array[], int SIZE)
{
    int unsortedValue;
    int scan;
    int index;

    for ( index = 1; index <= SIZE -1; index++)
    {
        unsortedValue = scores[index];
        scan = index;
        while (scan > 0 &&  array[scan - 1] < array[scan])
        {
            swapModule();

            scan = scan - 1;
        }
        array[scan] = unsortedValue;
    }
    return array[scan];
}


public static int[] swapModule(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    return b;
}

public static int[] displayScores(int scores[], int SIZE)
{
    int index;

    System.out.print("The scores are now displayed: ");
    for (index = 0; index <= SIZE - 1; index++)
    {
        System.out.print(scores[index]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The compiler tells you ***exactly*** which line and column are wrong. Please read them and go check what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I am still trying to find out how to solve each error. I don't know which direction to take on debugging what errors the compiler is telling me.

Comment: I gave you the information you want. All you have to do is check the compiler output, it will tell you which line has errors and in which column. Read the compiler output, go to that line and check if you are doing something wrong

Comment: Might even be a good idea to post some of the errors your are getting from the compiler.

Comment: one of the errors says "error: incompatible types return scores[index]" with an arrow pointing to the first bracket to the left of index. 

the second error states that "cannot find symbol" concerning "unsortedValue = scores[index]; 

I assume that one of the problems for the second error is because of the fact that I did not complete the first error. But I tried many ways and still do not know how to solve the first error.

Answer (score 2):

The first three things I noticed is that:

- In the getScores method you are returning an int value set by the position of the index variable instead of an array (which by the way is going to throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if it worked)
- the swapModule() method you are calling inside the insertionSort method does not have the parameters required
- the displayScores method must return an int[], but you're not returning anything.

Again, as the other people say, the compiler will tell you what's wrong. These are just a few errors I saw by taking a look at the code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you think you can help me a little bit more about how to fix some of these errors? I'm still very new to java and I do not understand the structure of how java is supposed to be written. This is my first language I am learning also. When you mean in your first point, did you mean that I should not include the index inside the array "scores"? I took off index and gave an error on the exact line requesting a .class, which I believe is the wrong direction where I am going.